# How to justify an element in matrix

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have a formula in LaTeX attached below. But I could not justify the position of `$+\infty$` symbol. I want it appear just after the `$\{$` and aligns to the left of the second term.

The LaTeX Code:

```
${{R}_{1}}\left( {{x}_{pi}},{{G}_{q}},{{x}_{qj}} \right)=\,\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   +\infty  & p=q  \\
   \underset{l=1}{\overset{d}{\mathop \sum }}\,({{x}_{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}_{qj}}\left[ l \right])\left( 2\left( {{x}_{qj}}\left[ l \right]-{{{\bar{x}}}_{q}}\left[ l \right] \right)+({{x}_{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}_{qj}}\left[ l \right])(\left| {{G}_{q}} \right|-1)/|{{G}_{q}}| \right) & p\ne q  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$
```

Comment: Another way would be to replace `+\infty` with `+\infty\hfill`.  This will move the `+\infty` to the left as desired.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `cases` environment (from the `amsmath` package):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
{{R}_{1}}( {{x}_{pi}},{{G}_{q}},{{x}_{qj}} ) = 
\begin{cases}
   +\infty  & p=q  \\
   \sum\limits_{l=1}^{d}\,({{x}_{pi}}[ l ]-{{x}_{qj}} [ l ])\bigl( 2( {{x}_{qj}} [ l ]-{{{\bar{x}}}_{q}} [ l] \bigr)+({{x}_{pi}}[ l ]-{{x}_{qj}} [ l])(\lvert {{G}_{q}} \rvert|-1)/\lvert{{G}_{q}}\rvert ) & p\ne q  \\
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed some superfluous `\left`, `\right` constructs and replaced one of them with `\bigl`, `\bigr`.

Comment: The formula works correctly in Latex. However, I'm not sure if I can export it to other environments such as MathType or not. By the way, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `array` instead, and then indicate the column specification. For example, using `@{}lc` produces a similar layout to your `matrix` yet `l`eft-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
{{R}_{1}}\left( {{x}_{pi}},{{G}_{q}},{{x}_{qj}} \right)=\,\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   +\infty  & p=q  \\
   \underset{l=1}{\overset{d}{\mathop \sum }}\,({{x}_{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}_{qj}}\left[ l \right])\left( 2\left( {{x}_{qj}}\left[ l \right]-{{{\bar{x}}}_{q}}\left[ l \right] \right)+({{x}_{pi}}\left[ l \right]-{{x}_{qj}}\left[ l \right])(\left| {{G}_{q}} \right|-1)/|{{G}_{q}}| \right) & p\ne q  \\
\end{matrix} \right.
\]

\[
{{R}_{1}}({{x}_{pi}},{{G}_{q}},{{x}_{qj}})=\left\{ \begin{array}{@{}lc}
   +\infty  & p=q  \\
   \sum\limits_{l=1}^d\,({{x}_{pi}}[ l ]-{{x}_{qj}}[ l ])( 2( {{x}_{qj}}[ l ]-{{{\bar{x}}}_{q}}[ l ] )+({{x}_{pi}}[ l ]-{{x}_{qj}}[ l ])(| {{G}_{q}} |-1)/|{{G}_{q}}| ) & p\ne q  \\
\end{array} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

The excessive use of `\left` and `\right` is not required. It introduces unwanted spacing and doesn't add any value. Consider using less-invasive constructions like `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

Comment: But When I paste your code in MathType, it does not change the display.